# ASUS H170M Plus RAM upgrade issue

Tags: memory, motherboard

I have an old but quite serviceable ASUS H170M Plus motherboard. It had 2 x 8GB DIMMs in DIMM_A1 and DIMM_B1, for a total of 16 GB of RAM.

I decided to give it its final upgrade: i5 to i7-7700 (I'm not a gamer so no i7-7700k) and 4 sticks of Crucial RAM from 2 32GB kits (DDR4 3200MHz CL22) (or 2933MHz or 2666MHz) Desktop Memory CT2K16G4DFRA32A (description from the Amazon listing). I also added a TPM while I was at it, but that's not relevant, I think.

The system booted into Windows 10, but I noticed in Task Manager that it only had 32 GB of RAM. I shut down and booted into the BIOS. There I saw that the initial screen showed all four RAM slots populated as expected and correctly detected as 16 GB sticks, but the total RAM showed 32 GB of memory. Another check in Windows Task Manager shows that it thinks I have two slots filled instead of four. Things I have tried:

- Re-seat all four RAM sticks
- Swap around the RAM sticks
- Played around a bit with the DIMM frequency in the BIOS, but I don't really know what I am doing
- Run Memtest

I didn't discover anything interesting. I have no idea why it's showing 32 GB and not 64 GB RAM, so if anyone has any suggestions, I'd greatly appreciate any insights.

Comment: Have you tried changing all the RAM settings in the BIOS to "Auto"? It might take a longer time to boot than usual after that as it does "memory training".

Comment: "I also added a TPM while I was at it, but that's not relevant, I think." - You are aware this was not required since your processor itself supports Intel's implementation of firmware-based TPM feature called Intel PTT.  I suspect the undetectable memory within Windows is caused by a miss-match in module sizes.  It's also possible that the memory is hardware reserved.  What is the exact layout of the memory? Be as specific as possible and refer to the manual when you indicate which module is in which location (A1,B1, A2, A2, etc) by performing an [edit] to your question.

Comment: Actually adding the TPM moduile was a waste of time, which I knew in advance, because the I7 in there is 7th gen, and if I want Windows 11, Microsoft requires 8th gen, which this motherboard doesn't support.

Comment: I got the TPM because I didn't realize it was useless to me at the time that I ordered it, and the motherboard does in fact have a place to add the TPM. Do you think the TPM affects anything?

The original post included the fact that all four RAM sticks are identical, but I'll include more specific information from the Amazon description:
Crucial RAM 32GB Kit (2x16GB) DDR4 3200MHz CL22 (or 2933MHz or 2666MHz) Desktop Memory CT2K16G4DFRA32A.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I didn't see such a setting. I'll look for it when I reboot. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Ramhound In case I wasn't clear enough, all four RAM slots in the computer are filled with the exact same module. I ordered two of the identical product (each package came with two DIMMs) and installed everything at the same time.

Comment: "Do you think the TPM affects anything?" - No; It's just unnecessary since your processor supports PTT.  However, as you found it the fact your processor is not supported, some motherboards do require a standalone TPM board in order to enable TPM within the firmware setting, despite the processor supporting PTT.  ASUS is known to have hardware like that.  Can you provide a RAMMap screenshot?

Comment: Sure, if you think it'll help in some way: https://imgur.com/a/B9l15E0

Comment: @AndrewMorton I did attempt to reset everything to "auto" in the BIOS on my last reboot. Nothing changed.

In the BIOS, I see that i shows all four RAM slots as filled with the correct 16 GB modules. And despite that, it says that I have 32G of memory.

I just don't understand what I'm doing wrong. No POST beeps are happening, either.

Comment: While you did mention you swapped around RAM sticks, did you try inserting just 1 RAM stick at a time and incrementally adding another 16GB stick like that to see how it behaves?

Comment: @patkim It's certainly worth a try. I think the next time I open up this machine (it's my daily driver, I'm typing this response on it now) I'll try each of the sticks in each of the slots one at a time, then two at a time in DIMM_A1 and DIMM_A2, then DIMM_B1 and DIMM_B2. Maybe it'll tell me something.

I'd suspect needing to re-seat the CPU and inspecting those pins, because I upgraded it at the same time, but all four DIMMs are detected in the BIOS, and I'm not getting POST errors, that's probably not it.

Comment: As per manual you should  populate A2 & B2 together with one set of dual channel kit. So I suppose if you have 2x16 + another 2x16, then one pair goes into A1 & B1 & another pair into A2 & B2. I hope that's how you populated all 4 existing.

Comment: Just check what is the lowest frequency available in Firmware options and try setting the frequency to lowest like 2100 or 2133 etc and check with those settings.

Comment: @patkim All four DIMMs are identical. But I'll try various permutations. I had already tried lowering the frequency to 2133, but I didn't go below that. It defaults to 2400, and behaves the same way at 2133.

I saw conflicting things about the frequency in the online documentation I've read. Specifically, I saw in one location: "4 x DIMM, maximum 64 GB, DDR4 2133 MHz", which is why I tried that, but to no avail.

Comment: I just checked using CPU-Z, and in fact it can see all four of my DIMMs.
Screen shot: https://imgur.com/a/MPfJKg8

Comment: Strange as it sounds, I've solved the issue. I had upgraded the bios to the latest version so the MB would support my new i7-7700. I decided to reinstall the same BIOS again. Boom, everything is fine now. I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I had updated the BIOS some weeks earlier to the latest supported version from the ASUS site, so that the MB would support my new i7-7700. I decided to reinstall that same version of the BIOS, and after the system restarted, the RAM was fully recognized both by the BIOS and by Windows. Everything is now working as expected.

I got the clue from here:
https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/only-half-of-my-ram-shows-up-in-bios-and-windows.3545052/

Thank you to all who tried to help.